# Java casting Object/String arrays

Tags: java, casting

I'm playing with Java to see how it works but I have some doubts about some kind of castings. Consider the following piece of code:

```
String[][] s = null;
Object[] o = null;

o = (Object[][]) s; // compile-time correct
```

Now, consider the following example:

```
Object[][] o = null;
String[] s = null;

s = (String[]) o; // compile-time error: Cannot cast from Object[] to String[]
```

Why does that happen? I'm confused.

Comment: You're not casting from `Object[]` to `String[]`. You're casting from `Object[][]` to `String[]`

Comment: The first example works because an `Object[]` is an `Object` (everything is an `Object`).

Comment: Please explain why you want to cast arrays of different dimension. This is obviously not very meaningful.

Comment: @martinhh He is *"playing with Java to see how it works"*.

Comment: @Gendarme that's what I wanted to know. Thanks.

Comment: You can't make a 2-dimensional array into a 1-dimensional array.

Comment: But why can i make 1-dimensional array a 2-dimensional array? (casting)

Comment: An `Object[]` is not necessarily one-dimensional. It could be any dimension you like. An `Object[][][][][]` is an `Object`, so your `Object[]` can contain several `Object[][][][][]`, making it six-dimensional.

Comment: @Gendarme: and not to forget: an `Object[]` could also be an `int[][]`,etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's failing because it's deterministically (i.e. always and can only ever be) wrong.

`o` necessarily contains arrays of objects.  These can NEVER be Strings.

The first sample you have, a String array can be typed as an object.

We can illustrate this if we remove an "array nesting". 
Consider:

```
String[] myStringArray = null;  //instantiation not important
Object someObj = myStringArray; //no problem since arrays are Objects
```

What you're doing in the second example amounts to

```
Object[] myObjectArray = null;  //instantiation not important
String someString = myObjectArray; //compile time error, since an Object[] is never a String
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice that this doesn't give your compile error:

```
Object[] o = null;
String[] s = null;

s = (String[]) o;
```

`Object[][]` to `String[]` will give incompatible type error.
`Object[]` to `String[]` will work normally.